# css hover drop down menu disappears when trying to select menu option

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have been searching for a fix for my code for a while now.

I have a drop down menu that displays the content of the menu after you hover over a static object, however when you attempt to select one of the items (you move your mouse off of the static object) the items disappear (are set back to display: none)

my code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="menuContainer">
    <div class="menuItem first">
        <div class="settingsIcon"></div>
        <div class="text">Account Settings</div>
        <div class="downArrowIcon"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="settingsMenu">
        <div class="menuItem">Manage clients</div>
        <div class="menuItem">Manage specials</div>
        <div class="menuItem">Manage users</div>
        <div class="menuItem">Logout</div>
    </div>
</div>';
```

CSS:

```
div#menuContainer div:hover + div#settingsMenu{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

div#menuContainer div#settingsMenu{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the `display:none;` section is above the hover section (because its read top-down, you want priority appropriately), but also to have `display:block;` when hovering over the settingsMenu itself.

The code:

```
#settingsMenu{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#menuContainer div:hover + #settingsMenu,#settingsMenu:hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

[Here is a jsFiddle to show](http://jsfiddle.net/YrVJS/).

Comment: The jsFiddle helped out a lot. It appears my div#settingsMenu was messing things up... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @plantTheldea,  https://codepen.io/vishal590/pen/RwxKodr, could you help me with that

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding:

`div#settingsMenu:hover{display: block;}`

Haven't tested it, but it seems like that would work.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is attach the :hover state to the `div:menuContainer`, rather than the `div`s inside. Also, you don't need the `+`

The following should work:

```
#menuContainer:hover div#settingsMenu{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

EDIT: below is a CodePed illustrating the above:

http://codepen.io/braican/pen/yIjLs

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using lists instead of divs, which is much cleaner and can be extended for submenus easily. Here is a sample:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            nav ul ul {
                display: none;
            }

            nav ul li:hover > ul {
                display: block;
            }
            ul {
                list-style: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="settingsIcon"></div>
                    <div class="text">Account Settings</div>
                    <div class="downArrowIcon"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Manage clients</li>
                        <li>Manage specials</li>
                        <li>Manage users</li>
                        <li>Logout</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (it happaned few times to me) the problem isn't priority in order, but in layers of CSS. 
**z-index** is a property that gives CSS another dimension.

In my example, z-index from slider was messing with my dropdown, simple

```
.submenu {
    ...
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

fixes the problem.

(.submenu is `<ul>` of dropdown list)

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a boder-top to get the dropdwon menu closer to the hover-enabled object to avoid that breach and gave the border top a background color that ryhmes with the object containers color and boom, it works....
In this case you will not have to deal with z-indexing.

```
boder-top: 26px solid red;
```

[image: A border-top with its solid inherited background color from hover-enabled object container]