# Bootstrap - Dropdown goes away on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with a navbar example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp). I would like the navbar dropdown to be the full width of the page and to show the dropdown on hover.

I managed the full-width capability by setting `position:initial;` in the dropdown class and setting the `width:100%;` in the dropdown-menu class.

The problem is that when `position:initial` is set, the dropdown disappears when you hover over it to click one of the links.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Here's what I've tried:

1. Set the dropdown-menu class to display:none and the dropdown class to display:block.
2. Made sure the class set to display:none was above the one with display:block (according to the answer here: [css hover drop down menu disappears when trying to select menu option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863044/css-hover-drop-down-menu-disappears-when-trying-to-select-menu-option))
3. Removed all the padding around the navbar and navbar elements (according to this question here: [Dropdown menu on hover dissapears (using bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232985/dropdown-menu-on-hover-dissapears-using-bootstrap))
4. Set the list elements to display:block on hover so they will see there is a hover and the dropdown won't dissapear.
5. Tried different browsers. Same problem in Chrome and FireFox.

> ```
> .navbar {
>     background-color: transparent !important;
>     border-color: transparent !important;
>     border-radius: 0 !important;
>     padding-bottom:0 !important;
>     padding-left:8vw !important;
>     padding-right:8vw !important;
> }
>
> .nav a{
>     color:#000000 !important;
>     padding-bottom:0px !important;
>
> }
> .dropdown-menu {
>     border-radius: 0px !important;
>     border: solid !important;
>     border-width: 1px !important;
>     border-color: lightgray !important;
>     border-radius: 0  !important;
>     -webkit-box-shadow: none  !important;
>     box-shadow: none  !important;
>     text-align:left !important;
>     padding-left: 1vw !important;
>     padding-right: 1vw !important;
>     padding-top:2vw !important;
>     padding-bottom:1vw !important;
>     display: none  !important;
>     width:100%  !important;
> }
>
> .dropdown{
>     position:initial  !important;
>   display: block  !important;
> }
> .dropdown-menu:hover{
>   top:0  !important;
> }
>
> .dropdown-menu>ul>li:hover{
>   display: block  !important;
> }
>
> .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
>   display: block  !important;
>   margin-top: 0  !important;
> }
>
> <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
>   <div class="container-fluid">
>     <div class="navbar-header">
>       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
>     </div>
>     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
>       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
>       <li class="dropdown">
>         <a class="dropdown-toggle"  href="#">Page 1
>         </a>
>         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
>           <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
>         </ul>
>       </li>
>       <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
> </nav>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need this bit of css:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

```css
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
  <p>This example adds a dropdown menu for the "Page 1" button in the navigation bar.</p>
</div>
```

*Make sure to view the StackSnippet at full screen, by clicking Full Page at far right of <kbd>Run Code Snippet</kbd> button*

Comment: Thanks, but that only works when you don't have `position:absolute` set. If I take away `position:absolute` out, then the dropdown is no longer the width of the screen. I am trying to get the dropdown to be the width of the screen and let me choose options on hover.

Comment: You should not need to put `position:absolute` on the nav bar. Do you have your nav bar inside a container? It should not be in any type of container; it should be 
an immediate child of `body` Otherwise, you can try putting `margin:0 -15px` *(Bootstrap is infamous for adding a 15px margin to both sides of containers)*

Comment: Sorry. I meant position:initial (that's what gets the full page dropdown). Anyway, your last comment did the trick. I added `margin-bottom: -15px !important;` (along with the code in the answer), and that seemed to do the trick. I thought removing all of the margin and padding settings would have worked. I didn't think about any default values. Thanks! (Oh, and can you add  part of that comment to the answer for the future please? That way I can mark it up.)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this answer which isn't helpful to OP, but might be helpful to someone else who lands here from Google.

For us the Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu items would disappear upon hover ONLY in Firefox. Check out this insane behavior:
[image: Firefox dropdown items disappearing on hover]

The problem ended up being that Firefox seems to dislike when the parent of a transformed element is set to `display: inline;` (actually it was a `span` for us, but same deal).

To solve the issue I added:

```css
span.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
```